# Looping video is not seamless in unity AVPro Media Player

Tags: c#, windows, unity-game-engine

I am trying to use the loop option on a AVPro Media Player, with a small (6sec, 25MB) perfectly looped video, but there is a small "freeze" when looping.

My code is very simple:

```
public MediaPlayer avMediaPlayer1 = null;

void Start()
{
    avMediaPlayer1.OpenMedia(new MediaPath(AppConfig.VideoFile1, MediaPathType.AbsolutePathOrURL), false);
    avMediaPlayer1.Control.SetLooping(true);
    avMediaPlayer1.Control.Play();
}
```

I have tested for instance with [this video](https://www.videvo.net/video/glowing-purple-grid-lines-tracking-in/393674/)

There always a stutter (or quick freeze) at the loop. (PC with I7 processor, Windows 10, NVMe drive, GTX1050)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a seamless loop with AVPro Media player, you need to encode the video in `keyframe-only` or keyframe every `1` frame (like in Premiere Pro), and remove any audio track.